# In astronomy Is there a name for the exact time between solar noon and sunset?

Tags: earth

Like there are names for various events such as sunset, sunrise, solar noon, solar midnight, astro, nautical and civil twilight, what exactly is name for time between sunset and solar noon. Afternoon it is but what exactly between these two points? Is golden hour the only subcategory for the afternoon?

I did come across the word midafternoon. similarly, midnight, midmorning and midevening. but then again midafternoon would mean 3 o clock or does it mean point between solar noon and sunset? because midnight in general is more acceptable as 12 o clock. is it?

Comment: "Golden hour" is a photographical term rather than astronomical term.

Comment: This question might be better asked on an English Language Learners site.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no such word better than "afternoon". I can't think of a situation that would require technical language for this period of time, the exact point halfway. When astronomers want to be technical about time they use UTC or UT1 or AT1 or any of the other "times". When they want to talk about more loosely defined periods they use "morning", "afternoon", "evening" just like everybody else.

"Mid-afternoon" is an ill-defined period, from about 2pm to about 4pm

Comment: It's raining, cold and windy  where I am so I naturally thought of the word [*siesta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siesta). :-)

Comment: The question's asking about the point, not the period.

Comment: If you have interpreted the question differently, feel free to add an answer.

Comment: @JamesK I've no clue what the answer could be! I'm just pointing out that "but what exactly between these two points?" suggests that they're after a specific time, not a fancy word for "afternoon".

Comment: What? No references to the time at which the drinking of Camellia sinensis-based beverages is called-for?

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing technical documentation, you could define, within your document, that "mid-afternoon" means the instant midway between noon (mean or apparent?) and sunset.  You will need to specifically define what that instant is when sunset does not occur (polar day or polar night).  Or you can ignore the seasons and declare that this moment is defined to be always 15:00 apparent solar time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Islam has a word, (Asr). The name of their prayer which takes place exactly between solar noon (Dhuhr) and sunset (Maghrib). I was trying to figure out the name for the time exactly between sunrise and solarnoon, as Islam does not call to prayer then. Islam also has names of prayer opposite solar noon (mid night Isha) and again at sunrise (Fair).

Comment: Welcome on the site! I think, the OP wants an exact time interval length. Although I don't think that noon and sunset could be really exact.